# How to check body is empty in iframe's document element?

Tags: javascript

Want to check whether the `body` element is empty in a `iframe` area which generated by Google Ad. Here is what I have tried and the result retuned. It not works well. Maybe the method is not right.

```
<iframe id='abc' scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" data-load-complete="true">
    #document
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <scirpt>...</script>
                <scirpt>...</script>
                <div>...</div>
            </body>
        </html>
</iframe>

var iframe = document.getElementById("abc");
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
alert(iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName("body"));
// It printed: [object HTMLCollection]
alert(iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0).innerHTML);
// It printed: "". But here it isn't empty.
```

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, works fine here, https://jsfiddle.net/h9od2nsL/

Comment: What populates your iframe? It doesn't have an src in what you shown to us. Is the markup inside it something that you really have in your HTML code? That won't get rendered in browsers that do support `<iframe>` (nowadays all?)

Comment: @Kaiido It's auto generated by Google Ads. Want to check whether the ad has data.

Comment: And when do you call this code? What makes you think that at this time it is not actually empty.

Comment: @Kaiido Want to check it when the page loaded.

Comment: But you understand that from what you have posted in the question there is no way for us to know what this means? When do you call these methods? When is set the content of this iframe?  From what we have, your code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/h9od2nsL/2/ So the problem lies somewhere else in your setup. You need to explain it to us.

Comment: _“It's auto generated by Google Ads. Want to check whether the ad has data.”_ - so that’s an iframe that loads content from a different domain then? Then you of course have no access to its content via JS _at all_, keyword Same Origin Policy. (Plus, not sure if their terms even allow you to try and interfere with their ad delivery system in any such way, Google is usually pretty strict about that.)

Comment: @Kaiido The google ad generated `iframe` with `data-load-complete` attribute. But I tried `iframe.hasAttribute('data-load-complete')` to check whether can handle it, failed. Something like `<iframe id="abc" data-load-complete="true">`.

Comment: @misorude Even the page loaded and generated `<iframe id="abc" data-load-complete="true">`, can't handle the `iframe`?

Comment: It can be handled in this case: https://jsfiddle.net/h9od2nsL/7/ But not work when handle the source generated by Google Ad script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if an html element has children you could use the [HTML DOM children property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp) or the [childNodes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) property:

Here's a general example from W3Schools:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get the tag names of the body element's children.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var c = document.body.children;
    var txt = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        txt = txt + c[i].tagName + "<br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not mix up "W3C" and "w3school", they have no relationship whatsoever.

Comment: TY - just corrected it - it's still early in the morning ;)

Comment: It looks good. But not work under `iframe` area. Returned `undefined` when tried `alert(iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName("body").children);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName("body").childNodes
```

Comment: Try to use childNodes

Comment: It not work. Also tried `iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes`, got `[object NodeList]`.